# Private Variable access

Tags: java, private, inner-classes

Why am I able to directly access `p`'s private `number` attribute within `Striker`'s implementation of the `hasSameNumber` method? Seems as though using the getter should be the only (if not, best-practice) way to access it. What am I missing?

```
public class Football {

    public static abstract class FootballPlayer {
        private final int number;

        FootballPlayer(int num) {
            number = num;
        }

        int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        abstract boolean hasSameNumber(FootballPlayer p );
    }

    public static class Striker extends FootballPlayer {
        Striker(int num) {
            super(num);
        }
        boolean hasSameNumber(FootballPlayer p ) {
            return this.getNumber() == p.number;
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:

The accepted answer shows why this is permissible - thanks! What would be the preferred/best-practice way to access `number` though - by getter or direct?

Comment: The equivalent C++ code would not be valid. You can add a language tag like Java to get an answer for a specific language.

Comment: The edit is an opinion-based question and therefore not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java - the access to *number* occurs within the body of *Football*, thus is allowed.

[JLS 6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

I admit I was surprised by this specific example.

Comment: ah great, thanks

Comment: is there a clear best practice to apply here? Use the getter or access the attribute directly?

Comment: I'd tend to saying *number* should be a protected field (to show intent, even if the language allows access to privates) and the subclasses should just read it directly.  In this case, simple-minded getters have no benefit.

Comment: Yes, I would agree. I think if I hypothetically _had_ to choose between directly accessing the private variable or a getter, I'd go for the getter, but yes, protected signals far clearer intent